# How Sibling Class Accessing Other Sibling Class Member function i using explicit casting works in C++?

Tags: c++

I created the following classes:

```
    class A
    {

    };
    class B :public A
    {
        public:
        void p()
        {
            cout<<"P";
        }
    };
    class C:public A
    {

    };
```

I tried to access the member function p() defined in class B using class C's dynamically created object.

```
    C* c = new C();
    ((B*)c)->p();
```

I was expecting that program will crash as there in no object of class B.But it worked and produced output p.How does it work?

Comment: *Undefined behavior* can sometime cause a crash. Or seemingly work. Or [summon nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Just don't do bad stuff.

Comment: And the big lesson here is to *never* use C-style casting, and instead see it as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: You need to get rid of the idea that bad C++ must cause a crash. It may cause a crash or it may not. Bad C++ code has *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: the method `P` is not using any members, hence it appears to work, doesn't mean that it does work in any meaningful sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work. Your program has [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), which means that you have *no guarantee* on how the program will behave, as long as you don't have compiler-specific additional guarantees. It does not mean that you *will get an error*. It *may seem* to work, or it may not.

It is undefined behavior, because the explicit cast `(B*)c` will translate into

```
reinterpret_cast<B*>(c)
```

as `static_cast<B*>(c)` is invalid (because `B` is not derived from or base of `C`).

Because there is no `B` object at the address `c`, the resulting pointer will still point to the `C` object.

Calling the `p()` non-static member function through this pointer then has undefined behavior, because the pointer doesn't actually point to a `B` object.